# Hide the gear icon (Site Actions) for all users except Admin

Tags: sharepoint-online, security-trimming

How to hide the gear icon (Site Actions) for all the users except the Admin group?

Answer (score 1):

Put your gear icon between SpSecurityTrimmedControl to hide or show based on user permission.

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server"
Permissions="AddAndCustomizePages">
Your Gear ICon
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

or use below:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID = "spstcSiteActions" runat = "server" PermissionsString = "ManageWeb">

<span ribbon">

<PublishingSiteAction:SiteActionMenu runat="server"/>

</span>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Comment: What do you mean by **"Your Gear ICon"**? Where it is used?

Comment: the span of your gear icon. do inspect element

Comment: @TaranGoel, is this in the master page?

Comment: Yes gear icon is part of master page

Comment: I have used this code. But it is not working.<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID = "spstcSiteActions" runat = "server" PermissionsString = "ManageWeb">

<span ribbon">

<PublishingSiteAction:SiteActionMenu runat="server"/>

</span>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>   Is there anyway to work on this?

Comment: You need to find your gear icon span in the master page and then replace it with my second code or just wrap your gear icon inside with my 1st code. I ll try to give you a step by step tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I have used sp services for finding the user is admin or not then based on user  hiding the gear icon and code placed in master page, see below.

```
    <body>
    .....
   <script type="text/javascript" src=".../jquery.min.js></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src=".../jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).bind("load", function() {
               $().SPServices({
                  operation: "GetUserInfo",
                  userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
                  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                    var UserAdmin = $(xData.responseXML).find("User").attr("IsSiteAdmin");  
                    if (userAdmin  == "False")  
                    {   
                    $('#O365_MainLink_Settings').hide(); // gear icon id
                    }
                    }
                });
            });         
        </script>
    </body>
```

Working fine for me check this 
[image]